# Play framework 2.5 reads optional filter

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have the following reads function for parsing JSON files.

```
 case class tables(col1 : Option[List[another case class]], col2 : Option[List[another case class]], col3 : Option[List[another case class]], col4 : Option[List[another case class]])


implicit val tablesRead: Reads[tables] = (
        (JsPath \ "col1").read(Reads.optionWithNull[List[data1]]).filterNot(_.get.isEmpty) and
          (JsPath \ "col2").read(Reads.optionWithNull[List[data2]]).filterNot(_.get.isEmpty) and
          (JsPath \ "col3").read(Reads.optionWithNull[List[data3]]).filterNot(_.get.isEmpty) and
          (JsPath \ "col4").read(Reads.optionWithNull[List[data4]]).filterNot(_.get.isEmpty)
        ) (tables.apply _)
```

I want to then insert the JSON into a database after having validated it. I have therefore declared the following function.

```
def createFromJson = Action.async(parse.json) { request =>
    request.body.validate[jsonWrapper] match {
      case JsSuccess(data, _) =>
        for {
          dbFuture <- dataFuture(data.userID)
          lastError <- dbFuture.insert(data.tables)
        } yield {
         Ok("Success\n")
        }
      case JsError(errors) => Future.successful(BadRequest("Failed :" + Error.show(errors)))
    }
  }
```

This works and correctly rejects JSONs looking like this:

```
{"tables":{"col1":[],"col2":[],"col3":[],"col4":[]}, "userID":"irrelavent"}
```

and accepts JSONs with actual data in, like so:

```
{"tables":{"col1":[{data1}],"col2":[{data2}],"col3":[{data3}],"col4":[{data4}]}, "userID":"irrelavent"}
```

But want i need is something that does this but also accepts a JSON with missing fields

```
{"tables":{"col1":[{data1}],"col2":[],"col3":[{data3}],"col4":[{data4}]}, "userID":"irrelavent"}
```

And preferable ignore them (i.e. return something like :
`{"tables":{"col1":[{data1}],"col3":[{data3}],"col4":[{data4}]}, "userID":"irrelavent"}`)

Is this possible to do?

Many thanks,

Peter M.

Comment: What does your `tables` class look like? Why not just use `Json.reads[tables]` instead of writing your own reader? The reader generated by the `Json.reads` macro automatically accepts missing fields if the field has an `Option` type.

Comment: @dtech i've added the my tables case class. The Reads is from the play.api.libs.json package, so, if i'm not mistaken, i am using the Json.reads. beleive the fact that each member of my case class is an optionis causing the problems i'm having.

Comment: if I understand correctly you want validate and accept Json for all col2 varaiants: 1. omitted, 2. exist with empty array, 3. exists with filled array?

Comment: No, I want to ignore all empty fields (e.g. col1:[]) and accept everything else while validating the key values (so that I can't include any random keys). Hope that is a clearer explication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can automatically generate a `Reads[tables]` using `Json.reads` macro with the behavior you want:

```
implicit val tablesRead: Reads[tables] = Json.reads[tables]
```

If the fields is missing from the JSON the column will be `None`.

On a minor note, the common form in scala is to start a class name with a capital letter so you should rename `tables` to `Tables`.

Comment: I had to tweak a bit of my code (the way i send JSONs) but it works now. Thanks, i remember starting off like this and not getting it to work exactly how i wanted and ended up over complicating things. And thank you for the class name norm, i always forget them...